# What was Caruana's plan in playing c6 against Carlsen in Game 10 of the Clutch Chess International?

Tags: opening, online-chess

In Game 10 of the 2020 Clutch Chess International, Caruana played `c6` in response to Carlsen's `9. Nd5`.

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Clutch Chess International"]
[Round "10"]
[White "Carlsen, Magnus"]
[Black "Caruana, Fabiano"]
[Result "1-0"]
[WhiteElo "2881"]
[BlackElo "2773"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 d6 4. Nc4 Nxe4 5. Qe2 Qe7 6. Ne3 Nc6 7. Nd5 Nd4 8.
Nxe7 Nxe2 9. Nd5 c6
```

What was Caruana's plan in making this strange move, since the white knight can just gain the rook through `Nc7+`?

Answer (score 6):

If White goes for **11.Nc7+**, then Black can reply **11...Kd8 Nxa8 Nxc1**, however if Black played **10...Nxc1** directly, **11.Nxc7+** would win an extra pawn.

Note **10...c6 Bxe2 cxd5** would have been OK for black.

Comment: What’s black’s compensation for being down the exchange?  Stockfish has this position at +4!

Comment: @NoahSnyder Black probably trusted to get his knight out before White could. Chess is very easy when you can look it up in Stockfish

Comment: It seems implausible to me that Caruana thought he could get his knight out, after Nc3 the knight on c1 is threatened and has nowhere to go.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: The games are 10 minutes so mistakes are not uncommon.  In this case the mistake was missing 9...Nd4!, threatening a Nxc2+ fork of his own